# Divisibility of sum of factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does $$p \mid 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + \cdots + (p-1)!$$ ever occur for any prime $p$?

My friend told me about this problem, but I don't know the source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens when $p=3$, but fails when $p=2$, so it only works for some primes.

Comment: Thank you. I had overlooked p=3 which is embarassing.. and my computer program was wrong - I fixed it now and asked an updated questio. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337053/second-part-of-the-factorial-sum-divisibility-question