# Is it true that if $p\neq5$ is a prime number then $1^p+2^{p-1}+\cdots+(p-1)^2+p^1\not\equiv0\pmod p$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

> Is it true that if $p\neq5$ is a prime number then $1^p+2^{p-1}+\cdots+(p-1)^2+p^1\not\equiv0\pmod p$?

If $p=5$ then $1^5+2^4+3^3+4^2+5^1\equiv0\pmod 5,$ but there is no such prime $p\leq40000$ any more, can you prove it or give a  counterexample?

**PS:** If $p>5$ could be a composite number, then $p\in \{16,208,688,784,2864,9555\cdots\}$ also works.

Comment: The naive heuristic argument says that there should be infinitely many primes with the sum congruent to 0 but this could be quite hard to prove because they're distributed _very_ sparsely; you should only expect roughly three instances with $p\lt 10^6$!  For related discussion, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405944/an-infinitude-of-congruence-condition-primes and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337053/second-part-of-the-factorial-sum-divisibility-question/ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$p=81239$ is a counterexample.

Comment: How did you come up with this?

Comment: @Kunnysan Just a brute-force search, nothing sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a $\sum\frac 1p$ distribution, similar to "If $p \mid 10^x-1$ then so does $p^2$".  This has solutions for $3$, $487$, and $56598313$, and no other values under $120^4$.

One just has to go out and have a look.