# The Remainder of $\sum _{ i=1 }^{ p-1 }{ i^{ i } } $ Divided by $p$

Tags: number-theory

What is the remainder of  $\sum _{ i=1 }^{ p-1 }{ i^{ i } } $ divided by $p$ when $p$ is a prime number?

I first conjectured that it would be equal to $1$ modulo $p$, but numerical evidence showed that this was not true. In fact, their values seemed rather random. For $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37$ they follow as $1,2,3,5,3,11,0,0,10,21,18,31$ respectively. This sequence did not appear on the [oeis](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C3%2C11%2C0%2C0%2C10%2C21%2C18%2C31&sort=&language=&go=Search).

I was not able to come anywhere near a closed form for this equation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405944/an-infinitude-of-congruence-condition-primes (see the link to MO) There is not reason to expect anything like a closed form. Most likely it behaves basically like a random sequence.

Comment: @quid Yes, I thought so as well. Then is there a chance we could at least approximate the remainder?

Comment: I do not think so.