# Primes $p$ which satisfy $p \mid \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i!$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

This question is inspired from @Mathphile's problem:

> The value$\sum_{i=1}^n i!$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is only semiprime for $n=3,4$

One can easily solve this conjecture by knowing that $9 \mid \sum_{i=1}^8 i!$ which implies that $9 \mid \sum_{i=1}^n i!$ for any $n \geqslant 8$. We can notice:
$$p \mid \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i! \implies p \mid \sum_{i=1}^ni! \quad (n \geqslant p-1)$$
Are there finitely or infinitely many primes of this form? If there are an infinite number of them (which heuristically seems to be the case), we consequently have $\sum_{i=1}^n i!$ to have an arbitrarily large number of divisors (or prime divisors) $\forall$ $n>N$ for sufficiently large $N$.

Can we extend this to $p^k \mid \sum_{i=1}^{p^k-1} i!$ (for this to hold, it must hold for all powers $p^j$ for $1 \leqslant j \leqslant k$)?

Comment: It is possible that there might be a proof involving Wilson's or Wolstenholme's theorem. Any progress is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Second part of the factorial sum divisibility question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337053/second-part-of-the-factorial-sum-divisibility-question)

Comment: Note:  the duplicate question does not contain a complete answer (which I expect is not known).  But it does have some useful heuristics and computer runs.

Comment: @Haran Did you find some primes that satisfy that divisibility condition?

Comment: @Grešnik I only found $3$ and $11$

Comment: @Peter In what range?

Comment: @Grešnik  Upto $p=10^5$